# Drive Table internal error. The developer of this script needs to provide additional authorizations before it can run

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to add a simple Drive Table model to a clean project, but as soon as I do that and launch a preview, I start getting this error in the log at launch and the app is essentially dead in the water.

I've tried to figure out what this error actually implies and what I'm supposed to do about it, but so far I've only managed to fail spectacularly.

I'm also getting some warning about `appmaker.dataservice.brix.RealtimeCaller` which doesn't look like anything to me, but might be related to the problem.

Here is the full error log (TestDB is the name of the model in this case):

```
(W) appmaker.dataservice.brix.RealtimeCaller: Realtime connection: HTTP status code is not available.

(W) appmaker.dataservice.brix.RealtimeCaller: Realtime connection: HTTP status code is not available.

(E) Drive Table internal error. Please try again. Caused by: The developer of this script needs to provide additional authorizations before it can run. (HTTP status code: unknown) Error: Drive Table internal error. Please try again.

(E) Executing query for datasource TestDB: (Error) : Drive Table internal error. Please try again.

(E) Executing query for datasource TestDB failed.
```

These are the steps I took to generate this error:

1. New Project -> Blank Application
2. Create Model -> Google Drive Table (name: TestDB)
3. NewPage -> datasource -> TestDB
4. Preview
5. Select my G Suite account
6. Allow app to view and manage the files in my Google Drive
7. Click "Review permissions" when prompted
8. Select my G Suite account
9. App launches and triggers errors.

Among other things, I've tried reloading, building a new preview, deploying, creating a new project and changing the access permissions to the model.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you tried this using incognito mode?

Comment: Yes. I've also turned off all extensions, as well as tested with different browsers.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me. You mind exporting the app and sharing the zip if it doesn't have compromising data?

Comment: @Morfinismo The Hello Data! sample from https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/work-with-data/ produces the same result for me. It does indeed feel like this is some kind of bug and not just an implementation error on my part. I've opened an issue on Google's bug tracker.

Comment: I just tested that demo and didn't get any error. If Drive is enabled for your domain, then this is definitely a bug. Perhaps they might be doing some kind of maintenance before launching App Maker into General Availability.

Comment: @DanielPerván Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @ItsJustMe Sadly, no. It seems like Google later deprecated and killed off Drive Table in favour of Cloud SQL. I haven't heard anything about it since then.